# Accessing a specific key in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to access the "title" section (key?) of this JSON object using NodeJS. I can return the entire object, but every time I try to access the key, undefined is returned.

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 119,
            "title": "Roadhouse",
            "url": "https://funsite.com/2021/03/20/funny/",
            "date": "2021-03-20"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 208,
            "title": "New Sites",
            "url": "https://coolsitestuff.com/notes/coolsite/",
            "date": "2021-03-17"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "title": "woah sites!!",
            "url": "https://now.lettuce.com/then/2021-0000/",
            "date": "2021-03-07"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 120,
            "title": "mynewalbumn",
            "url": "https://notarealsite.com/2021/03/06/next-album/",
            "date": "2021-03-06"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 140,
            "title": "fightingthemans",
            "url": "http://fightcats.com/2021/03/06/keyfights",
            "date": "2021-03-06"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "title": "biggest lettuce youll ever see",
            "url": "https://morelettuce.com/then/biggestlettuceleaf/",
            "date": "2021-02-28"
        }
    ]
]
```

NodeJS

```
const fs = require('fs')


fs.readFile('./data/links.json', 'utf8', (err, fsToString) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(fsToString);
    console.log(data.map(link => link[link.url]))
})
```

I've tried for loops and indexing that way but I haven't been able to get anything out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 arrays, either loop over both of them or access it using `index`

```js
let data =[
    [
        {
            "id": 119,
            "title": "Roadhouse",
            "url": "https://funsite.com/2021/03/20/funny/",
            "date": "2021-03-20"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 208,
            "title": "New Sites",
            "url": "https://coolsitestuff.com/notes/coolsite/",
            "date": "2021-03-17"
        }
    ]
]


data.map(link=> console.log(link[0].url))
```

Comment: You pointed out that I had several arrays in each loop, I'm super unfamiliar with how json is structured so I went back and looked at it. The problem I was dealing with actually stemmed from where I structured the JSON in the first place, apparently I needed to do a bit more processing on my backend when I fetched the data from postgres. Ended up with this line to get rid of the extra brackets and fixed my problem

data = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cur.fetchall()))

Appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Your json is array of array objects, you need to access all arrays by index, you can use flatMap and map methods.

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "id": 119,
    "title": "Roadhouse",
    "url": "https://funsite.com/2021/03/20/funny/",
    "date": "2021-03-20"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 208,
    "title": "New Sites",
    "url": "https://coolsitestuff.com/notes/coolsite/",
    "date": "2021-03-17"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 13,
    "title": "woah sites!!",
    "url": "https://now.lettuce.com/then/2021-0000/",
    "date": "2021-03-07"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 120,
    "title": "mynewalbumn",
    "url": "https://notarealsite.com/2021/03/06/next-album/",
    "date": "2021-03-06"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 140,
    "title": "fightingthemans",
    "url": "http://fightcats.com/2021/03/06/keyfights",
    "date": "2021-03-06"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 14,
    "title": "biggest lettuce youll ever see",
    "url": "https://morelettuce.com/then/biggestlettuceleaf/",
    "date": "2021-02-28"
  }]
];

console.log(data.flatMap(i=>i.map(f=>f.url)))
```

Comment: Ah damn I didn't see this, that would have really helped me clear this up faster. I appreciate your post, I wrote a reply to the one I selected as solved above

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is trying to access an undefined object property.

**Solution:**

Replace the `link[link.url]` for `link[0].url`. So that the full line is

```
console.log(data.map(link => link[0].url))
```

Or if you want the titles:

```
console.log(data.map(link => link[0].title))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(
  data.flat().map(link=>link.url)
);
```

```
console.log(
  data.map(item=>item[0].url)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your JSON file holds an array of arrays and each nested array contains one object. Therefore data.map(link => link[0].title) should return array of titles

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays and each one with just one position. For the code you posted you're just missing the index of each element.

If you change your code to this you'll get the array with the URL's you're looking for

```
fs.readFile('./example.json', 'utf8', (err, fsToString) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(fsToString);
    console.log(data.map(link => link[0].url))
})
```

Happy coding ;)!